# Practical problems with difficult posteriors

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, posterior

I'm looking for difficult Bayesian inference problems to test out different Monte Carlo sampling methods. I've mostly been looking at Hamiltonian Monte Carlo based algorithms and in particular, I've been using the trick of using the hessian at the Maximum A Posteriori point for the mass matrix.

What are some practical inference problems with difficult posteriors to sample from?

Comment: I think [genetics](http://mbe.oxfordjournals.org/content/16/12/1791.abstract), [dynamical systems](http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/6/31/187.abstract) among other areas present challenges in sampling from the posterior of the parameters. For this reason [ABC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) is becoming popular. The posterior of the parameters of [Stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) is another example of difficult posteriors to sample from as well. Is this the sort of examples you are looking for?

Comment: I think so, though more specific problems/datasets would be helpful as well as problems that are relatively simple to set up (I could get them running in a couple of hours on my home computer).

Comment: The posteriors are often complicated in hierarchical models because the normalization constants of the first stage priors are included in the posteriors.

Comment: @John Salvatier, you don't mention [Girolami and Calderhead, 2011](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/inference/rmhmc/) in the question -- I assume you've looked at the example inference problems in that paper?

Comment: @Procrastinator, John Salvatier is looking for problems where the unnormalized target density can be computed for a given state, but has a shape that makes MCMC convergence difficult. ABC is for problems so difficult that the unnormalized target density can't be computed for a given state, making standard MCMC impossible.

Comment: @Cyan Thanks for this. That was not clear from the question.

Comment: @Cyan, I have read that paper, but I hadn't thought of looking at the examples for this purpose. I'll take a look at them. Thanks for clarifying my question.

Comment: @John Salvatier, it may also be worthwhile to search that paper's discussants' references for hard problems. In particular, the discussant Mark Transtrum did his Ph.D. research on approaches for difficult non-linear least squares optimization in a class of models he termed "sloppy". Since just finding the global optimum is difficult in these models, they'd certainly pose a challenge for MCMC.